# DYLD error: Library not loaded: @rpath/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, openssl

I have a react-native app that consumes OpenSSL-Universal as dependency.

OpenSSL is being called from CPP Code which is bridged via an react-native swift library. In the Simulator the whole code runs fine. But when I build the App for production, Archive it in X-Code and install it on a real i-Phone, I get following error:

```
DYLD error: Library not loaded: @rpath/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL
```

I have added the `OpenSSL.framework` to Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries and to

General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content

What am I missing here? Its really confusing to me that it runs fine on the Simulator, but not on a real device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to not OpenSSL library integrated properly

## Solution 1:

- Project settings
- Select Target
- Select the `General` tab
- Under `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content`, click on the plus button.
- Find the `OpenSSL.xcframework` from the list and hit Add.
- select `Embed and sign` from `OpenSSL.xcframework`
- run xcode build again

## Solution 2:

1. add this line into Podfile

```
pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', :modular_headers => true, :configurations => ['Release']
```

2. just run `pod install` in the ios root directory
3. run the build

## Solution 3:

For whatever reason in `Project settings > Select Target > Build Settings > Framework Search Paths` this:

[image: Screenshot 2023-04-07 at 9 45 48 PM]

but the Release ones were missing a bunch of those so I added these 2:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/OpenSSL-Universal/Frameworks"
"${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/OpenSSL-Universal"
```

Then both debug and release builds worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that feels like a workaround:

1. Clone and build the [openssl for iPhone](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone) repository
2. copy the arm64 (iPhone) build into the project (lib and include folder)
3. Register the library via "Other Linker Flags" in XCode, so a -I[PATH TO "include" FOLDER] and a -L[PATH TO "lib" FOLDER]

Although this works, it would be nice to find an option that just works out of the box without any additional configuration. Now I have to revert those changes if I want to run on a simulator because the simulator will of course crash with the linked iPhone OpenSSL build